# Test accordion isCollapsed with overflow hidden and maxHeight

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

### What I Need

I need a way to test if an accordion isCollapsed or not. I tried seeing if there was a way to grab if the maxHeight hasChanged, but from what I have read, it doesn't include measurements within the dom objects for the tests

---

### The Problem

Writing the following test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Accordion from './Accordion';
import AccordionItem from './AccordionItem';

const accordionTitle = 'Title: Hello World';
const accordionContent = 'Content: Hello World';

function TestContainer() {
  return (
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionItem title={accordionTitle}>
        <p>{accordionContent}</p>
      </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
  );
}

describe('Accordion', () => {
  const userViewing = userEvent.setup();

  it.only('expands content on item control click', async () => {
    render(<TestContainer />);
    expect(await screen.findByText(accordionContent)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    const accordionItem = screen.getByRole('button', { name: accordionTitle });
    userViewing.click(accordionItem);
    expect(await screen.findByText(accordionContent)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Results in the following Error:
[image]

---

### The Reason

I think this is because the content component still exists in the DOM, but is only being hidden by the `overflow: hidden;` and `maxHeight: 0 or heightOfContent`(for animation purposes).

---

### The Component Code

Accordion.tsx:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

function Accordion({ children }: PROPS): JSX.Element {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

interface PROPS {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default Accordion;
```

AccordionItem.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';
import AccordionControlClick from './AccordionControlClick';
import AccordionContent from './AccordionContent';
import { useStyles } from './Styles';

function AccordionItem({ title, children }: PROPS): JSX.Element {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={isCollapsed ? classes.accordionItemClosed : classes.accordionItemOpen}>
      <AccordionControlClick
        title={title}
        isCollapsed={isCollapsed}
        toggleIsCollapsed={setIsCollapsed}
      />
      {children !== null && (
        <AccordionContent isCollapsed={isCollapsed}>{children}</AccordionContent>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

interface PROPS {
  title: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export default AccordionItem;
```

AccordionControlClick.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './Styles';

function AccordionControlClick({ title, isCollapsed, toggleIsCollapsed }: PROPS): JSX.Element {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <button
      className={classes.accordionControlClick}
      type="button"
      onClick={() => toggleIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
    >
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <span className={isCollapsed ? classes.iconChevronWrapper : classes.iconChevronWrapperRotate}>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down" />
      </span>
    </button>
  );
}

interface PROPS {
  title: string;
  isCollapsed: boolean;
  toggleIsCollapsed: (isOpen: boolean) => void;
}

export default AccordionControlClick;
```

AccordionContent.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './Styles';

function AccordionContent({ isCollapsed, children }: PROPS): JSX.Element {
  // variables
  const componentDomRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const componentHeight = useRef(0);
  const classes = useStyles();

  // setup
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    componentHeight.current = componentDomRef.current ? componentDomRef.current.scrollHeight : 0;
  }, []);

  // render
  return (
    <div
      ref={componentDomRef}
      className={classes.accordionContent}
      style={isCollapsed ? { maxHeight: '0px' } : { maxHeight: `${componentHeight.current}px` }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

interface PROPS {
  isCollapsed: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default AccordionContent;
```

Styles.ts

```
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';
import { cssColors, cssSpacing } from '../../utils';

const accordionBoxShadow = '2px 3px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
const accordionBoxShadowTransition = 'box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;';

export const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  accordionContent: {
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    width: '100%',
    padding: `0 ${cssSpacing.m}`,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    transition: 'max-height 0.3s ease-in-out'
  },
  accordionControlClick: {
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: `9px  ${cssSpacing.m}`,
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    outline: 'none',
    backgroundColor: `${cssColors.backgroundLevel2}`,
    cursor: 'pointer'
  },
  accordionItemClosed: {
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: cssSpacing.l,
    border: `2px solid ${cssColors.accordionTitleBorder}`,
    borderRadius: '8px',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    transition: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
      border: `2px solid ${cssColors.accordionTitleBorder}`,
      boxShadow: accordionBoxShadow,
      transition: accordionBoxShadowTransition
    }
  },
  accordionItemOpen: {
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: cssSpacing.l,
    border: `2px solid ${cssColors.accordionTitleBorder}`,
    borderRadius: '8px',
    boxShadow: accordionBoxShadow,
    transition: accordionBoxShadowTransition,
    '&:hover': {
      border: `2px solid ${cssColors.accordionTitleBorder}`,
      boxShadow: accordionBoxShadow,
      transition: accordionBoxShadowTransition
    }
  },
  iconChevronWrapper: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transform: 'none',
    transition: 'transform 300ms ease'
  },
  iconChevronWrapperRotate: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    transition: 'transform 300ms ease'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AccordionContent.tsx file, I added in the following visibility

```
style={ isCollapsed ? { maxHeight: '0px', visibility: 'hidden' } : { maxHeight: `${componentHeightRef.current}px`, visibility: 'visible' } }
```

In the test file I make the following changes to test if the content is `ToBeVisible` vs `toBeInTheDocument`:

```
it.only('expands content on item control click', async () => {
    render(<TestContainerOneItem />);
    const accordionContentContainer = (await screen.findByText(accordionContent)).parentElement;
    await waitFor(() => expect(accordionContentContainer).not.toBeVisible());
    const accordionControlButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: accordionTitle });
    await userViewing.click(accordionControlButton);
    await waitFor(() => expect(accordionContentContainer).toBeVisible());
});
```